# Uniform Convergence and Continuity of a Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I want to show that the following function converges uniformly and that it is continuous on $[T,-T]$

$f(x): = \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {\sin(x/n)}{n}$

Weierstrass crieteria:

We have $\vert \vert\dfrac {\sin(x/n)}{n}\vert\vert \leq \vert \vert \dfrac{\dfrac{T}{n}}{n} \vert \vert = T/n^2 \le \infty$ $\forall T \in \mathbb{R}$ Also $\Sigma T/n^2$ converges therefore $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {\sin(x/n)}{n}$ converges uniformly

Therefore using Abel's criteria, $f(x)$ is conitnuous on $[T,-T]$

**Is that the right way to do it?**

Comment: Your inequality is... not enough. For $T\neq 0$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{T}{n}$ is not exactly convergent, is it? So the *"Therefore it converges uniformly"* is (wrong) wishful thinking. In short: you may want to use the additional $\frac{1}{n}$ you discarded in your first inequality, it's there for a reason.

Comment: @ClementC. I edited my question, would that work?

Comment: Well, you may want to be more precise in your notations (what norm are you writing? the subscript $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$ may help if you deal with functions, but here you seem to want $\lvert\cdot\rvert$ (absolute values) and the quantifier "for all $x$"; and write $[-T,T]$, **not** $[T,-T]$, for instance). But that's the gist of it, yes.